# In C# can we update a text file line with new record while reading the same file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-processing

I have .text File (with 400K rows). I need to read that file and If i find (AB,CB,DE,FG) in certain position (35, 2) in each row, I need to replace that with new value which I already have in dictionary object.
this is my dictionary with list of policy number and respective group:

```
ListofPolicy[10001,MM]
ListofPolicy[10005,KK]
ListofPolicy[10011,NN]
ListofPolicy[10018,YY]
ListofPolicy[10020,GG]
```

etc...

This is my sample .txt file: I need to read the line.Substring(35, 2) will tell us which group it is.

```
P00002398911100010131220111061553XXAB549099QSTJDK6016
HUI001004117577408867289000000007209171              
P00002398918100058882220111061459YYLT518435BIVQZC1855
P00002398916726561656220111103331XXKY518435BIVQZC1855
PPP001CSTON                                          
P00002398911001136778220111103329XXCB511100QSBUPO1128
HUI001004117577408867289000000007209171              
P00002398911001888877220111103323XXKI518435BIVQZC1855
PMT001CSTON                                          
P00002398911002066656220111103320YYFG511100QSBUPO1128
HUI001004117183000000007209169              
P00002398917409185763220111103316XXDF511100QSBUPO1128
```

How do I approach this ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do (an example or 2 would help). It appears you want to read _sample.txt_ and if one of the letter pairs is found, replace it with something else. I would read the file, line-by-line, looking for any one of the letter pairs.  If not found, I'd write the line to a new temp file.  If it is found, do the replacement before writing the line.  When you get to the end of the input, delete the original file and rename the temp file to match the original file.

Comment: Maybe you can just write a grep for this? Or some other easy find and replace tool? Imho a whole C# app is overkill for this, and not necessarily very efficient

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need something like that:

```
        string content = ""; 
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("path\\to\\your\\file.txt"))
        {
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\your\\file.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string line in content.Split('\n'))
            {
                if (yourDictionary.Keys.Contains(line.Substring(35, 2)))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine($"{line.Substring(0, 35)}{yourDictionary[line.Substring(35, 2)]}{line.Substring(37, line.Length - 37)}");
                }
                else
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's not necessarily efficient to redeclare your list in a loop. A compiler may move the declaration outside the loop since the list isn't modified, but you can't count on that. Also, a list isn't the best data structure for Contains if there's a non-trivial number of elements. In fact, you mention `yourDictionary` which isn't declared in code, but presumably has as keys the same information you have in the list (and Dictionary.Keys.Contains is quite efficient).

Comment: You are absolutely right, I'll fix it.

Comment: I'd also not overwrite the original file until you know processing succeeded, e.g. if there's an exception on line 42, the original file is lost (write to a temp file, copy when successful, delete the temp file)